# Having Excel Fields Auto Update when New Data Added

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel doc that starts with some fields that come from calculations done on the rows below it.  To do the calculations I currently have a module with about 4 functions that loop through rows 20 through N(first blank cell).  These functions are called straight from the cells at the top of the sheet.  The problem is that the calculations at the top are not updating whenever someone adds/removes data from the rows below.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functions are Excel VBA user-defined functions called from worksheet cells, then you will get this not-recalculating behaviour if the UDF refers to cells that are not in the input parameters of the UDF.

If this is the case a good solution would be to define some Dynamic Named Ranges that expand/contract as data is added/deleted and use them as input to the function.

Another solution would be to add Application.Volatile to your UDF, but this has the undesirable side-effect that your UDFs will be recalculated at every calculation which can be painfully slow.

Comment: Interesting... what do you mean by "if the UDF refers to cells that are not in the input parameters of the UDF"? Is it that if the UDF tries to write data to cells other than those it accepts as its input parameters, then those cells won't update automatically?

Comment: if a function Jean(A1) has VBA that references cell B2 then Jean will not recalculate when cell B2 is changed. This is because Excel's smart recalc engine only tracks volatile functions and references in formulas and functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `Worksheet_Change` event to accomplish such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In your sheet module, add a `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rngChanged As Range)

    ' Call your subs and functions here

    MsgBox "You just changed something!"

End Sub
```

Note that the `Worksheet_Change` sub *must* have one and only one argument of type `Range`. Excel will make it a reference to the range that was changed by the sheet user. If you want to observe its behaviour, try placing this line in the sub:

```
rngChanged.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```

Read more e.g. [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).